# Web based simple interface for elderly user

Tags: web

I have an elderly grandfather who enjoys using his computer for email and games. He is unable to effectively use more advanced interface elements like the 'start menu' in windows. Currently he is running on an Ubuntu Matchbox interface which has a single large button at the bottom for each of the programs he might be interested in using. There are stability issues with matchbox however, and it does not easily allow for remote changes.

Is there a paid or free web based service which could be run within a fullscreen kiosk-mode web browser which provides essentially a number of control buttons at the bottom and an IFrame for viewing page content (such as email client, web based-games, etc.)?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is off topic for Super User. Try asking on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out [Eldy](http://www.eldy.eu/), which is available for Mac, Linux and Windows.

I've been meaning to install it on my grandmother's laptop for quite some time.

[image: Eldy]

Comment: this one is great! thnx man!

Answer (score 1):

It might not be ready for your use, but it sounds like you want some thing similar to [ChromeOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_OS).  I think someone made a live CD for it